# How to interrupt/resume a list in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I want to produce output something like this:

> > 1`.` List item
> >
> > 2`.` Another list item
>
> Paragraph of comments on list items 1 and 2.
>
> > 3`.` Further item
> >
> > 4`.` Final item

I'm sure I've seen a nice way to interrupt and resume lists in this way (without explicitly setting some counter), but I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Note that you can define some custom commands like `\newcommand{\savecounteri}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}` and the corresponding `\restorecounteri` to make these solutions prettier.

Comment: BTW, this question was asked one year later on TeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I like enumitem for this sort of thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item List item
  \item Another list item
\end{enumerate}

Paragraph of comments on list items 1 and 2.

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Further item
  \item Final item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution from `enumitem`. I personally love this package since it gives cross reference efficiently..

Answer (score 12):

The TeX FAQ lists several ways of doing this. Read [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=interruptlist) for full details.

I've successfully used the [mdwlist](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdwlist) package (which is part of [mdwtools](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdwtools)) in my own documents. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdwlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item List item
\item Another list item
\suspend{enumerate}

Paragraph of comments on list items 1 and 2.

\resume{enumerate}
\item Further item
\item Final item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to Dervin Thunk for providing the FAQ link.

Comment: +1 since this is the only answer that answers the actual question (how to interrupt and resume lists without explicitly setting some counter).

Comment: @Dervin Thunk - I was going to remove my answer because the page you linked to described this and the other possibilities. I'll happily do this if you undelete. I didn't click to read the link - sorry.

Comment: Hi, Chris. No, your answer is more to the point. It should stay. But thanks for offer, I appreciate.

Comment: And by the way, if you say you didn't read it, then that's enough for me.

Comment: nice... i had no idea about this package :P

Comment: @Dervin Thunk: Please undelete your answer anyway. I found that link extremely helpful, and I think it contained the best answer to the question (I like the `enumitem` package way of interrupting a list a bit better than the `mdwlist` approach).

Comment: thank you, it works. However when it resumes the counter, it also changes its style. If I use (1), (2) , once resumed it will use 3, 4 without (). Maybe I missed something..

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first;

\item second;
\end{enumerate}

This is a paragraph.


\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{2}
\item third;

\item and so on...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**edit**: as pointed out by Dervin Thunk, I hardcoded 2 here.

so, here's a solution that seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{tempcounter}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first;

\item second;
  \setcounter{tempcounter}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}

This is a paragraph.


\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{\value{tempcounter}}
\item third;

\item and so on...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that you're hardcoding the values... what happens if you add a 3rd item in he first enumerate? You wil have to change all other hardcaded vals... my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`newcounter`](http://www.aip.de/~weber/doc/LaTeX/ltx-271.html) and [`usecounter`](http://www.aip.de/~weber/doc/LaTeX/ltx-338.html) to get around this -- here's [an example](http://www.aip.de/~weber/doc/LaTeX/ltx-260.html#example).

Comment: He asked for a way that does not include "explicitly setting some counter".

Comment: This doesn't use an **explicit** count -- he doesn't have to explicitly start at 3 after he breaks the list at 2 items.

Comment: The link to "an example" in this answer is broken. Use this url instead:  http://www.ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-260.html#example